# Is this really p2p?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc, p2p

I'm using socket.io-p2p here to try and send an image file.
Since it's p2p I presume that the file is not being uploaded to a server and it's sent directly to the connected peers. I managed to transfer a file with the code I have but I am pretty unsure if this is really a p2p transfer because it seems to me that the file is getting uploaded to my server first, then sent to the other peer instead of an actual p2p connection between two devices. I see spikes in upload and download in DU Meter regardless of whether I'm sending the file between tabs or between two different devices on different networks. 
I know that the signalling part is done on my server but that should be about it if this is truly p2p.
Of course, I could be wrong so I'm asking for an assessment.
What do you guys think?

server.js

```
var app = require("express")();
var express = require("express");
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var p2pserver = require("socket.io-p2p-server").Server;
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
var path = require("path");

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
io.use(p2pserver);

var peerNum = 0;

io.on("connection", function(socket) {

  console.log("Peer " + peerNum + " connected");
  io.emit("peer-num", peerNum);
  peerNum++;

  ss(socket).on("file", function(stream, data) {

    var filename = path.basename(data.name);

    var parts = [];

    stream.on("data", function(data) {
      parts.push(data);
    });

    stream.on("end", function() {
      socket.broadcast.emit("file", parts);
    });

  });
});

server.listen(80,'someServer', function () {
  console.log("Listening on 80")
});
```

client.js

```
// this file is meant to be browserified
var P2P = require("socket.io-p2p");
var io = require("socket.io-client");
var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
var socket = io();
var opts = {autoUpgrade: true, peerOpts: {numClients: 10}};
var p2p = new P2P(socket, opts);
var $ = require("jquery");

p2p.on("peer-num", function(num) {
  console.log("You are peer number " + num);
  $(".peerNum").html("You are connected to " + num + " peers.");
});

p2p.on("file", function(stream) {
  //console.log(stream);

  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob(stream));
  document.getElementById("receivedImages").appendChild(img);
});

$(function() {
  $("#file").change(function(e) {
    ss.forceBase64 = true;
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var stream = ss.createStream();

    ss(socket).emit("file", stream, {size: file.size,name:file.name});
    var blobStream = ss.createBlobReadStream(file);
    var size = 0;
    blobStream.on("data", function(chunk) {
      size += chunk.length;
      console.log(Math.floor(size / file.size * 100) + "%");
    });
    blobStream.pipe(stream);
  });
});
```

Comment: Get better measuring tools than DU Meter, figure out between which IPs the data is transferred. Also, some p2p solutions may have relay fallbacks if nats get in the way.

Comment: You could use wireshark to capture packets that leave your PC, inside this packets you can find IP addresses of your PC and destination host, and content of send data, hope this helped